# Opening Spring jsp in a popup window

Tags: spring, jsp, popup

My application needs a solution like Outlook mail: opening an other page as popup window on the parent window. The application is Spring 3 based and uses jsps. How do I make a popup out of my application page in order to make it work as intended at least in most common browsers?

I've tried target and window.open, without getting them work properly in Firefox.

Comment: Without seeing what you've tried, it's impossible to help--the `target="_blank"` on a link should work fine.

Comment: target = "_blank opens a new tab for me in Firefox.

Comment: And where would you adjust the size of the window with that?

Answer (score 1):

Just as an example, the Spring travel sample app contains a jsp which is launched via a pop-up.

```
<a id="changeSearchLink" href="hotels/search?searchString=${searchCriteria.searchString}&pageSize=${searchCriteria.pageSize}">Change Search</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.AjaxEventDecoration({
        elementId: "changeSearchLink",
        event: "onclick",
        popup: true,
        params: {fragments: "searchForm"}       
    }));
</script>
```

This shows how a link is decorated with an Ajax Event to launch searchForm.jsp when the link is clicked.